# Is there a way to remove this error " attempt to apply non-function "

Tags: pie-chart

**pie(ABK$Gender(1, 24), col = rainbow(24), radius = 0.9)**

Error in pie(ABK$Gender(1, 24), col = rainbow(24), radius = 0.9) :
attempt to apply non-function